# Setting SOAPHeader with PHP

Tags: php, soap

I am new to SOAP, and I am a little unsure how to do this. The documentation from the provider is very limited, so it's been a matter of a little trial and error since they don't offer support. The documentation states that the XML should start with the following - and I assume then that they mean header.

```
POST /Economy/InvoiceOrder/V001/InvoiceService.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: api.url.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://url.com/webservices/GetDeliveryMethods"
```

I have tried to set the header the following way:

```
    $header = new SoapHeader(
                            "POST /Economy/InvoiceOrder/V001/InvoiceService.asmx HTTP/1.1",
                            "Host: api.url.com",
                            "Content-type: text/xml;charset='utf-8'",
                            "Content-length: ".strlen($xmlfinal),                            
                            "SOAPAction: http://url.com/webservices/GetDeliveryMethods"

                        );
    $invoiceService->__setSoapHeaders($header);
```

However, the request returns as "Bad request". My XML looks fine according to the providers examples.

The XML is created as both a file on the server and stored in $xmlfinal.

Does anyone have any hint on what I might be doing wrong? I appreciate any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "SoapHeader" appears in the XML in `<header>` elements. This is probably not what you want.

You can set headers in the stream context and pass that to the soap client

```
$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header' => 'YourHeader: value'
    ),
);

$ctx = stream_context_create($opts);

$client = new SoapClient('the.wsdl', array('stream_context' => $ctx));
```